# Akka Stream: What is the difference between Unzip and Broadcast?

Tags: scala, stream, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image: graph]

I am trying to create this flow using `Flow.fromGraph`

- I can do `join` using `Zip[B, C]` which takes in 2 streams
- I can do `split` in 2 ways:

  - using `Broadcast[A](2)`
  - using `UnZip[(A,A)]`, preceded by a `.map(a -> (a, a))`

Both `map(f1)` and `map(f2)` are custom flows I'm obtaining from included libraries, so I can't really modify them, so please don't say `.map(a => (f1(a), f2(a)))`

What are the differences between the 2 cases, or are equivalent?The only thing I found different was `Broadcast`'s ability to cancel only when *all* downstreams cancel (`eagerCancel = false`) which is its default behavior, as against `UnZip` (which does what broadcast does with `eagerCancel = true`)

Also, what happens in case of failures in either of the 2 paths? i.e. what is the impact if, for a specific element, f1 throws an error?

Additionally, say if we don't have an `f2` function (so no map operation) and we want to emit `(b,a)` at the end, should f2 be replaced by an identity flow, or can it be skipped all together? (if latter, would you *ever* use an identity flow?)

```
val split = builder.add(BroadCast[A](2))
val join = builder.add(Zip[B, A])
val F1: Flow[A, B, NotUsed] = Flow[A].map(f1)
val I = Flow[A].map(identity)

split ~> F1 ~> join.in1
split ~> /* I ~> */ join.in0 // do i need the commented part?
```

Probably this helps with internal buffers/back-pressure ?

Comment: maybe FlowWithContext helps here, but at this point it is still in development and isn't sufficiently ready to handle this... also there isn't much docs/examples of FlowWithContext

Comment: Similar here: https://gist.github.com/davideicardi/d3b383e5945a44252931582f83ecadc2

Answer (score 1):

They are both *Fanout* operators; however

`Unzip` from the docs:

> Takes a stream of two element tuples and unzips the two elements ino two different downstreams.

While `Broadcast`

> Emit each incoming element each of n outputs.

Therefore we can conclude that Unzip is just a Broadcast with `n = 2`; but **importantly** if the elements are a tuple, Broadcast will just create `n` outputs of the same tuple. Unzip will create 2 outputs **each** for element `A` and `B`